# Need help to understand Spark SQL execution flow for a given condition

Tags: apache-spark-sql

We have a spark code written in scala :

```
val sqlContent = "Complex hive query..."
val df = spark.sql(sqlContent)
df.coalesce(3).write.option("orc.compress", "snappy").mode("overwrite").insertInto(hivetable)
```

Here is the command to submit this code :

```
spark-submit --executor-memory 8G --num-executors 8  --executor-cores 4 --driver-memory 8G --queue ETL --conf spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100 --jars brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --conf spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --class com.abc.MySparkProgram --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster hdfs://user/com/abc/MySparkProject.jar <some input params>
```

When this job is executing, I captured screen shot from Spark-SQL yarn ui:
[image]

Here are my questions :

```
1- Please help me to understand the flow which is mentioned in above screenshot?

2- As I have set coalesce=3, which means all partitions/files will merge in to 3 partitions/files. But if you look at the last rectangle of above screen shot (i.e. Execute InsertIntoHiveTable rectangle), it is showing : "number of written files: 234" as well as "number of dynamic part: 234". Why? And this job took 1hr 30 mins to finish.

3- Every time when I submit this job with same input parameters, every time it shows me different "number of written files: 44" as well as "number of dynamic part: 44" in same "Execute InsertIntoHiveTable rectangle". Why? And this job took 25 mins to finish.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.